# Conversion from Decimal form to BCD

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

I have seen a way how to convert a decimal number to BCD (packed & unpacked) using 8,4,2,1 weighing forms but how to do it using 4,2,2,1 and 7,4,2,1 ? Any method please.Suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to represent 8 base 10 then it will be represented as follows:

```
A) 7421 code
   8(10)= 7+1 = 8        
   1 0 0 1 -> 7 4 2 1 code
   1x7+4x0+2x0+1x1=7+0+0+1=8
   8(10)=1001(7421)

B) 5421 code
   8(10)= 5+2+1 
   therefore   5 4 2 1
               1 0 1 1
  8(10)= 1011(5421)

C) 4221 code
   8(10)= 4+2+2
   therefore 4 2 2 1
             1 1 1 0
   8(10)= 1110(4221)
```

There you go. If this is helpful then please select this as an answer.

Comment: So,it means that for 5421 the number to be encoded shouldn't exceed 12 and same for 7421,4221?

Comment: @tonny Basic requirement of weighted codes are that weight must be chosen so that their number is not greater than 15 and not less than 9. Additionally, one of the weights must be 1 and another either 1 or 2. Ex: 8421,5421,4221.

Comment: So if you want to encode number as you said 12 in 4221 then encode 1 and 2 separately .

Comment: that's what i thought the same