# How are codes like 5421 and 2421 unique?

Tags: code-generation

For the number 6, if I need to represent it in 5421 code form, should I code it as 
1001 or 0110? Why should I choose the one over the other?

Similarly for the number 5 in 2421, is it 1011 or 0101?

Edit 1:

In a weighted binary code, the name of the code indicates the weight assigned to each place.

So if the code is 8421, the number 9 would be written as 1001 (8*1 + 4*0 + 2*0 + 1*1=9). And the number 5 would be 0101 (8*0 +4*1 +2*0 +1*1=5). In each case, no other combination of weights add up to the values (9 and 5).

Edit 2:

But for 5421, can the number 5 be represented as 1000 (5*1+4*0+2*0+1*0=5) as well as 0101(5*0 + 4*1 + 2*0 + 1*1 = 5)? Which one should be chosen? Similarly for 2421, which one to choose between 1011 (2*1 + 4*0 + 2*1 + 1*1 = 5) and 0101 (2*0 + 4*1 + 2*0 + 1*1 = 5)?

Comment: What's 5421 code form?

Comment: The binary weighted code (like 8421)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what that is.  I'm not familiar with the term "binary weighted code".  Can you give a self-contained description of what that is and how it works in the question, so that people who aren't familiar with it can understand what you are asking?

Comment: Is this adequate? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33063/conversion-from-decimal-form-to-bcd/33066#33066

Comment: Not for me.  Please edit the question to add a self-contained description of what you mean  by that.  Also, we need a definition.  An example is not a substitute for a definition that covers the general case.  Don't force us to reverse-engineer what it might mean from an example or two.

Comment: Thank you. For the time being, this is the best way I could put this through. Is it better now?

Comment: *Why should I choose the one over the other?* No reason. There is no canonical encoding, so you're free to choose whichever encoding you want. Your codes are not unique unless you come up with more constraints, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Codes like 5421 and 2421 are not unique, and this is one of their advantages. For example, 2421 is *self-complementing*: computing the 9-complement of a digit is the same as negating its bits. In textbooks you can find tables in which the authors choose one possible code for each digit, but this choice is arbitrary, and you might find different choices in different textbooks.

Let me also mention that BCD has been gradually losing favor, and I expect only old hardware to use anything other than 8421 (if at all). Most of the interest in BCD is historical, since modern architectures don't use BCD. I suspect that material about BCD is there mostly because of inertia, though BCD might still be used in conservative industries such as banking.